# Select query too slow only for some date ranges

Tags: php, mysql

Query took long time while look some specific date range. If I combined those date range there is no performance issue.. why its happening?

If I change order by primary id to date_time field its working fine.. But I want to sort by primary key id

```
SELECT * FROM wipes  WHERE site_id = "173" AND (report !="" OR report != null) AND date_time >= "2019-09-05 00:00:00" AND date_time <= "2019-09-05 23:59:59" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0 (Query took 188.8281 seconds.)

SELECT * FROM wipes  WHERE site_id = "173" AND (report !="" OR report != null) AND date_time >= "2019-09-06 00:00:00" AND date_time <= "2019-09-06 23:59:59" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0 (Query took 155.9838 seconds.)

SELECT * FROM wipes  WHERE site_id = "173" AND (report !="" OR report != null) AND date_time >= "2019-09-05 00:00:00" AND date_time <= "2019-09-06 23:59:59" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0 (Query took 0.3978 seconds.)
```

Comment: Add indexes to your table. How many rows do you have in your db?

Comment: Do you have an index on date_time? If not try adding one.

Comment: Short Answer: MySQL optimizer is costs based and can do a other acces plan when data sizes changes.. Long answer:  As this is a performance question we need at minimal a  `SHOW CREATE TABLE `wipes` and a `EXPLAIN <query>` for every query involved in the question. Without that we can't really help you..

Comment: Are you sure that your queries are running  without syntax errors ? `!= null` is invalid syntax, and should be replaced with [`IS NOT NULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: How many records are in the table.. Also how many record do match when you run the queries separeted..

Answer (score 0):

The reason the ORDER BY could be changing the speed is because the ORDER BY could force a SORT operation by the database. To avoid that perhaps the database is using the wrong index or maybe it's actually sorting. One way to fix this is to give the DB a HINT with USE INDEX (after using EXPLAIN) and another ways is to just provide a perfect index for your query. But, before you should give the DB hints, you should update the statistics to see if that helps the DB figure things out better on its own with

```
ANALYZE TABLE wipes;
```

Firstly, change

```
report != null
```

To

```
report IS NOT NULL
```

Secondly, add this index

```
ALTER TABLE wipes ADD KEY ( site_id, report, date_time )
```

Then the query will be fast.

Comment: @RaymondNijland  You test and see with USE.  I agree that you can't blindly hope. Also the characteristics of the DB change over time.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I hope you approve of my latest update. I think I did a good job of helping based upon the information available. Perhaps an upvote is called for ;-)

Comment: removed mine comments simply without table structures/engine you can't tell whats happening performance wise..  Also to avoid a long (possible offtopic) performance conversation in the comments about the costs based MySQL optimizer which is a heavy beast to understand..